# Does geom_jitter change geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I think I know the answer to this question, but I was trying to confirm and I have not been able to find documentation anywhere that does so. My question is if including a `geom_jitter` effects the results of `geom_smooth`. I am assuming that it does not because it wouldn't make much sense if it did, but would like confirmation.

Comment: No it doesn't, beside that the data in geom jitter also count towards the limits of position scales and such.

Answer (score 0):

Visual confirmation that the jitter does not impact the smooth, but does change the limits of the scales. Note the corners of the smooth still line up with the rectangle.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1.51, xmax = 5.42, ymin = 8, ymax = 36,
           fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1/15)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 5, height = 40) +   # extreme jittering!
  geom_smooth() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1.51, xmax = 5.42, ymin = 8, ymax = 36,
           fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1/15)
```

[image]